# Does Facebook reuse a personal profile URL once an account is deleted?

Tags: facebook

The following account was supposedly deleted on January 10, 2014 but I saved the URL so I could check to make sure it was deleted. On February 11, 2014 it shows a new account has been activated with the same URL. https://www.facebook.com/mike.jenkins.3720190

Or has this account been reactivated? When I pasted the URL prior to yesterday and followed the link previously it did show the "sorry this page has been removed" page. It shows that the account was created or that they joined FB on 2/11/2014.

Is it possible that someone with the same name Mike Jenkins was assigned the same URL upon creating a new account or is this account reactivated and in fact the same?

The fishy part is the /mike.jenkins.3720190 being exactly the same. I understand that there are many people with the same name but the auto generated extension is the concern that it is exactly the same as a supposedly deleted profile. I have attached images of the first one and the new one.
[image: Original Profile]
[image: New Profile]

Answer (score 2):

Yup, if a profile is deleted the URL of that page/profile is released to be used by someone else. Only way to not let this happen is to deactivate your profile rather than deleting it.

Answer (score 0):

I would have thought that it would keep the URL reserved in case you ever decide to re-activate the account.

So it would suggest that the account has been re-activated and updated.